# How to redirect the output from plain java class to httpservlet class

Tags: java, servlets

I have `HttpServlet` class called, let's call is `Test`. I can output anything from this class using `HttpServletResponse` object into my html page. Now, I have another a plain java class, let's call it `Home`, and in this class I need to out put something into the html page. Unfortunately, it doe snot work even I have tried to inherit `HttpServlet` from `Home` class and use `HttpServletResponse` object to out put.

Is there a way to redirect the output from the Home class to Test class ?

Here's the method doGetof my Test class, it create an object of home and call the method connectToHom() for authentication.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  ServletException, IOException {
       String tst = "username"
        tst = new Home();
        tst.connectToHome(tst); 

}
```

Here's the method connectToHome() of the class Home:

```
public void connectToHome(String tst){
  -> Try to login using tst,
  connect = Connection.open(tst);

  if(connect.getMessage()!=null){
    System.out.println("-- Error: " + connect.getMessage()); 
    return null;
 }
}
```

The above code works but it prints out on the console instead on the html page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Hi Boris, I have post the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you need to send an `OutputStream` ref. to `Home` class:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  ServletException, IOException {
    String tst = "username"
    tst = new Home();
    tst.connectToHome(tst, response.getOutputStream());   
}


public void connectToHome(String tst, OutputStream out){
  -> Try to login using tst,
  connect = Connection.open(tst);

  if(connect.getMessage()!=null){
    out.print("-- Error: " + connect.getMessage() + "\n"); 
    out.flush();
    return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, tahnk you! I will try that out and let you know. Thanks!